# Bootstrap 4 / AngularJS v4 popover binding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4, angular2-template

My binding is working on the page but not inside a bootstrap popover. Does AngularJS-v4 binding work differently inside a bootstrap4 popover?

**This works** inside the the html page but not in a popover:

```
{{photoset.photoNote}}
```

**This does not work** when inside a bootstrap4 popover template:

```
<a
[popover]="editCaption"
popoverTitle="Edit caption"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<ng-template #editCaption>
{{photoset.photoNote}}
</ng-template>
```

Comment: If you can upgrade to Angular 4 or 5, you could use ng-bootstrap [Popover component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples). Their components work better with Angular than the standard Bootstrap components.